# Align the "Main" and "Meta" links along the top of MSO and SO?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, user-interface, meta, design

I know this is extremely minor, but it's constantly driving me crazy.

On all other SE Sites, the [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and the [main](https://stackoverflow.com/) site links line up. You can click in the exact same spot to toggle between the meta and main sites without moving your mouse, or even looking at where you're clicking.

But this isn't the case for SO and MSO. MSO has an [about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) link along the top that no other SE site has, which means the [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and [main](https://stackoverflow.com/) links don't line up correctly when switching between the two sites, so I'm constantly ending up in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) or on the [about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) page instead.

I know it's a trivial matter, however would be a problem to make the [main](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) links in the top header line up correctly for SO and MSO, so that toggling between the two is as lazy as thoughtless as it is for other sites?

All you'd need to do is remove the [about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) link from MSO like you did for all the other SE sites, or rearrange the link order so that the [main](https://stackoverflow.com/) link is to the right of [about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) instead of to the left.

[image]

**Edit:** As [Gamecat pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161000/align-the-main-and-meta-links-along-the-top-of-mso-and-so#comment467328_161000), the [about] link visibility is based on your reputation, so the only reason why the two don't match on SO/MSO is because you have separate reputation between the main and the meta site.

So perhaps either make it visible regardless of reputation on SO and MSO?

Its never bothered me before by being there, but it has bothered me when I go to look for it and can't find it, so end up having to type it in my URL manually

Comment: The [about](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) link is present on all SE sites, but is displayed only if your rep is below 10k on graduated sites and 2k on beta sites.

Comment: The about link is shown on each site where you don't have enough rep to hide it. So either get more meta rep or lose some of your SO rep. ;-)

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe I never noticed that before, but you're right. I suppose the only reason my links don't align on MSO is because reputation isn't matched between SO and MSO, while on all other SE sites reputation of the meta site matches the rep from the main site.

Comment: But then again, even without the about link, there is some misalignment.  Looks like they want us to look before clicking.

Comment: to me, this seems to be EXTREMELY trivial. You can make a chrome bookmark and remove the title so it's just an icon :) How often do you constantly switch between the two without moving your mouse? Also, I thought Google Wave was discontinued? Also,

Comment: @iight It is discontinued... I guess that shows how often I use/update my bookmarks.... :) But honestly, I switch between the two quite often. Most of the time it's habit and laziness... I do it to go from Unanswered to Active questions since I don't like changing my cached sort order. Perhaps a better feature request would be to put the "about" link back, since I've been annoyed in the past trying to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a userscript that reinserts the `about` link on SO:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        SOabout
// @namespace   stackoverflow
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

var a = $('#hlinks-custom a[href="/faq"]');
var b = a.prev().andSelf().clone();
b.eq(1).html('about').attr('href','/about').end().insertBefore(a.prev());
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The about link automatically disappears once you receive the moderation tools on that site.
2. Re-arranging it would look silly. The about link is next to the faq link because logically they are both similar - information about the site. Splitting them up with a link in the middle would make little sense.
3. There's also a bubble that appears between review and chat when there are pending suggested edits, which would misalign the review link. Should we move that around too?

I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Threshold is either 10.000 or 5.000.

Comment: pretty sure it's 5k, because I don't see the link and I have 6k.  Rachel doesn't see it at 4k.

Comment: Thanks for the info about #1, but that doesn't make me any less annoyed that the link to toggle between the two sites shifts around on me if I only have mod tools on SO but not MSO (or vice versa). I understand your concern with #2, but think they could be rearranged to make sense, such as "review, chat, about, faq, main". In regards to #3, that doesn't make anything shift because everything is right-aligned, so only objects to the right of the main/meta link make it shift.

Comment: I just looked it up, it goes away when you receive moderation tools (so it's different on beta sites).

Comment: @Rachel: The suggested edits bubble appears to the right of the review link, so it would push the review link left. The bubble on the left of the review link is the flags count.

Comment: @animuson Oh I see what you're saying now. I don't care about the [review] link though since I have to look to click on it anyways. The only one that bothers me is the main/meta link, since I often click it multiple times without looking at or moving the mouse to toggle between the main and the meta site quickly. Its a habit I picked up from other SE sites, and SO/MSO is the only one where the links don't line up and I frequently end up clicking the wrong link

Comment: I'm very against splitting up the information links. Maybe if they're bored they can change the "faq" link to an "info" drop-down, which links the faq, about, and help (which would also achieve that "add help to the top-bar" feature request that's around here somewhere).

Comment: @animuson I wouldn't care if they included the [about] link on both pages, and that would probably be the simplest solution. I've never noticed the fact it's there, but I do notice when it's missing and have wondered where it went a few times when I wanted to view it and and had to type it in the URL manually since I couldn't find it. I never realized it went away with rep.

Comment: @animuson What about putting both `meta` *and* `main` after the `faq` links? That way those two stay aligned and `about faq` doesn't get broken up.

Comment: @Asad: I feel that's something for the community to decide. Personally, I wouldn't care because I almost never even use those two links. But for someone who does use them consistently, moving them over would throw them off quite a bit. I like the drop-down idea more, as then all the links are always available to everyone. I, being over 10k, do sometimes find myself wanting to visit the about page, and the only direct link to it is clear down in the footer.