# Show the [about] link on the top of the page regardless of reputation?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tour

I was looking for the [about] link a little while ago, and was quite annoyed to discover that it wasn't at the top of the page where it used to be.

It was [pointed out to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161000/align-the-main-and-meta-links-along-the-top-of-mso-and-so#comment467327_161000) that the link disappears automatically when you hit a specific amount of reputation (5K on graduated sites, 2K on beta sites), which explains where it went, but it doesn't lessen the irritation it caused by not being where I expected it when I wanted it.

I can understand hiding popup reminders based on rep, or large blocks of text that take up a lot of screen space, but hiding a small static link when a user hits a specific rep threshold is unexpected and very aggravating when trying to find the link in the future.

So I would like to request that the [about] link stay visible at all times at the top of the page, and not disappear based on reputation.

(I found out later that there is another [about] link in the footer of the page, but I would not have noticed that without another user pointing it out to me, as I was used to the link being at the top of the page, and would not have thought to look for it in the footer)

Comment: I've thought about this but I'm a bit on the fence about it. About *is* now way way more useful, but still mostly intended for first-time users. I too have been annoyed trying to find the about link, but I guess a large part of that is due to it being new and evaluating it/editing it on UX

Comment: @BenBrocka Most of the time when I'm looking for the link, I want to copy/paste it to a new user in a comment (its faster opening in a new tab and copy/pasting the url than it is to type out the site name and add the `/about` to the end of it), although there has been times when I want to look up something from the link for my own purposes as well.

Comment: I cannot see the about link on stackoverflow, and I have not reached 10k rep yet. Therefore, the requirements must be lower.

Comment: RE the copy/pasting: [we really really really need it to be a magic link!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165625/add-about-to-list-of-magic-links)

Comment: @JoshMein You're right, I think it's 5k not 10k. The comment that originally pointed that out to me was incorrect :)

Comment: @BenBrocka I agree with that, although a magic link still doesn't help me when I want to look at the site personally, such as to see the exact wording of something or to view an update

Comment: I'm curious about the downvotes.... do people really hate the idea of an extra word at the top of their page that much? Or is there another reason for the [about] link to be hidden for high-rep users that I am not aware of?